# Could not find artifact in jitpack.io, almost all dependencies in pom broken

Tags: java, maven, jitpack

I cannot seem to resolve dependencies in my POM. This project was working for me earlier this morning and is currently working on another machine, but somehow now my project is so borked that all my dependencies are broken, all my imports and most of my classes are just red underlines. I want to go back to where I'm no longer having dependency/pom/maven errors and can search for the original desiredCapabilities errors.

**Environment**: 
MacOS
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Java 8 and 11 are installed on my machine
Project SDK: Java 11
IDE: IntelliJ
Appium 1.16.0

**Trying to solve the original problem:**
1. Mvn clean install, with and without -U
2. Right click on project > Maven -> reimport
3. Tried to open on eclipse but this project uses graphql and I got errors that there weren't marketplace options for what I needed
4. Restarted intelliJ
5. Restarted my computer
6. Build -> Build project, rebuild project
7. Deleted my .m2 directory and tried a mvn clean install/mvn install etc, but this is where all my artifacts started breaking. Almost all dependencies now say "Dependency not found" when I hover
8. Tried updating maven indices from the pom
9. Blew out the repo and re-cloned it
10. Reverted to a previous commit

**The current error on mvn clean install is:** [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mobile-app-automation: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.automation.cm:mobile-app-automation:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.141.59: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.141.59: Could not transfer artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:pom:3.141.59 from/to central (http://jcenter.bintray.com): Authorization failed for http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59/selenium-java-3.141.59.pom 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]

**mvn compile** gives the error: "Failure to find org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:pom:3.141.59 in https://jitpack.io was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced
"

**Here is my pom, 90% of the dependencies are red:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.automation.cm</groupId>
<artifactId>mobile-app-automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.annaFedorchenko</groupId>
        <artifactId>automation-xray-integration-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.saucelabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>saucerest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.40</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DEPENDENCIES FOR THE API TESTING -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.apollographql.apollo/apollo-android-support -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apollographql.apollo</groupId>
        <artifactId>apollo-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/apollo-runtime-1.2.3.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apollographql.apollo</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/apollo-api-1.2.3.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, needed only for ANNOTATED nullable type-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>13.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/annotations-13.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.sparow199</groupId>
            <artifactId>apollo-client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- <rootPackageName>com.example.graphql.client</rootPackageName>-->
                        <!-- <skip>false</skip>-->
                        <!-- <addSourceRoot>true</addSourceRoot>-->
                        <introspectionFile>
                            src/main/java/com/automation/api/apiresources/config/schema.json
                        </introspectionFile>
                        <!-- <generateTransformedQueries>false</generateTransformedQueries>-->
                        <!-- transformedQueriesOutputDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/graphql-client/transformedQueries</transformedQueriesOutputDir>-->
                        <generateIntrospectionFile>true</generateIntrospectionFile>
                        <schemaUrl>https://qa-kong.command-api.kw.com/graphql/gql</schemaUrl>
                        <sourceDirName>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/automation/api/apiresources/config
                        </sourceDirName>
                        <!-- <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/graphql-client</outputDirectory>-->
                        <!-- <generateModelBuilder>true</generateModelBuilder>-->
                        <!-- <useJavaBeansSemanticNaming>true</useJavaBeansSemanticNaming>-->
                        <!-- <useSemanticNaming>true</useSemanticNaming>-->
                        <!-- <nullableValueType>JAVA_OPTIONAL</nullableValueType>-->
                        <!-- <suppressRawTypesWarning>false</suppressRawTypesWarning>-->
                        <!-- <generateKotlinModels>false</generateKotlinModels>-->
                        <!-- <generateAsInternal>false</generateAsInternal>-->
                        <!-- <generateVisitorForPolymorphicDatatypes>false</generateVisitorForPolymorphicDatatypes>-->
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Are you behind a web proxy that requires authentication? The HTTP 403 forbidden is   the only really relevant message here.

Comment: Good point, I thought of that, but shouldn't be as all my other automation projects have been working until now, and this one project was working as of 7am today

Comment: Get the jar from another machine and follow [these steps](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) to install it in your local m2 repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per JFrog, [as of Jan 2020](https://jfrog.com/jcenter-http/), JCenter is available only over https. Your repo snapshot has http instead of https.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: no idea how to create or read snapshots, but when the devs are eventually back, i'll bring that up, too and check back with ya

Comment: @JuliePixie revised answer to include repo info in POM. Try switching to https instead of http & see if it works.

Comment: Worked! I'm at least back to square whatever-i-was-before, thank you!!

Comment: thank you!! adding https instead of http in repository solved my problem .